# Call of overloaded 'println(char [4], int)' is ambiguous

Tags: arduino, serial-port, communication, arduino-uno

I've two Arduinos and I want to make them communicate via TX/RX. Arduino one as a sender, and Arduino two as a receiver. But I have a problem with the receiver code and get this error:

> call of overloaded 'println(char [4], int)' is ambiguous

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

This is my receiver code:

```
char str[4];

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int i=0;
  if (Serial.available()){
    delay(100); //allows all serial sent to be received together
    while(Serial.available() && i<4){
      str[i++] = Serial.read();
    }
    str[i++]='\0';
  }
  if(i>0){
    Serial.println(str, 4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two `Serial.begin(9600)` in the setup?
After the while loop, the `i` var is equal to `4`. Your biggest index in `str` array is `str[3]` (0-3), so you are accesing the `4th` index which doesn't exist.You should remove that `str[i++] = '\0'`, and if you want to make communication you should do something like :

```cpp
if (i > 0) {
  for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
    Serial.print(str[j]);
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: 'cause I use 2 arduino uno, when I use 1 uno and 1 mega, The other serial.begin is serial1.begin (only for mega). Ok thank you for the answer, I'll try it

Comment: what is this comment.... 2 arduino, ok. 1 uno + mega, also okay. but WHY 2 SERIAL.BEGIN???? u do understand that each needs to be uploaded independently?